# How to put RSpec/Capybara tests outside of the spec/requests directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec2

For some reason my team does not want our acceptance tests to exist in the spec/requests directory. Instead, they would like them placed in a new directory called acceptance that exists outside of the spec directory structure. So, my first question is, using RSpec, Capybara and capybara-webkit, is this even possible?

Here is my acceptance_spec_helper.rb file

```
require 'rubygems'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

# Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, :type => :request, :example_group => {
    :file_path => config.escaped_path(%w[acceptance])
  }

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

However, it does not seem that the application is actually being run in order to be tested.

And please, do not just say to put the tests back in the spec/requests directory without some very strong arguments to back up why that is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar where I had my specs in `spec/acceptance`, tagged them with `:acceptance => true`, and ran them with a separate rake task `rake spec:acceptance`

Check out this gist- https://gist.github.com/3858851.

Hope it helps